# Flutter/dart formatting data to instances not working

Tags: flutter, api, http, dart, formatting

So, I can receive the data and print it but it won't format correctly any more into a list. I have attached all the code below used to get the data and the models. Plus the print outputs. Can someone help me please.

**Getting the data**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:world_time/services/model/article_model.dart';
class News {


  String? city;
  List? articles;

  News({this.city});
  Future<void> getNews() async {
    try {

      Response response = await get(Uri.parse('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=$city&from=2021-12-05&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=MY API KEY'));
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(json);
      List<dynamic> body = json['articles'];
      articles = body.map((dynamic item) => Article.fromJson(item)).toList();
      print(articles);
    }
    catch (e){
      print("Caught error: $e");
    }
  }
}
```

**print(json)**

```
{status: ok, totalResults: 520, articles: [{source: {id: bbc-news, name: BBC News}, author: null, title: Unstoppable Salah closes in on more records - his year in numbers, description: As Liverpool's Mohamed Salah closes in on another record, BBC Sport takes a statistical look at his superb 2021., url: https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/59646200, urlToImage: https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/live-experience/cps/624/cpsprodpb/1269A/production/_122081457_mohamedsalah.jpg, publishedAt: 2021-12-16T08:49:23Z, content: Mohamed Salah has scored 36 goals in all competitions for Liverpool in 2021
I/flutter ( 2307): "He is phenomenal. For sure, at the moment, he is the best player in the world."
I/flutter ( 2307): Liverpool manager Jurgen Klopp may well … [+5278 chars]}, {source: {id: reuters, name: Reuters}, author: null, title: Man Utd face Villa, Leicester host Watford in FA Cup third round - Reuters, description: Manchester United entertain Aston Villa in the FA Cup third round, while holders Leicester City welcome Watford and West Ham United are at home
```

**print(articles)**
as articles is null, catch returns this

```
I/flutter ( 2307): Caught error: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

**article_model**

```
class Article {
  Source? source;
  String? author;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  String? url;
  String? urlToImage;
  String? publishedAt;
  String? content;
  Article(
      {this.source,
        this.author,
        this.title,
        this.description,
        this.url,
        this.urlToImage,
        this.publishedAt,
        this.content});
  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Article(
      source: Source.fromJson(json['source']),
      author: json['author'] as String,
      title: json['title'] as String,
      description: json['description'] as String,
      url: json['url'] as String,
      urlToImage: json['urlToImage'] as String,
      publishedAt: json['publishedAt'] as String,
      content: json['content'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

**source_model**

```
  String? id;
  String? name;

  Source({this.id, this.name});

  factory Source.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Source(id: json['id'], name: json['name']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your model, all of your variables are of type `String?` that is to say, the variables will be either `String` or `null`. But when you make the model, you assign all the variables like this: `variable: json['variable'] as String`, which means that if they are `null` they will throw an error, because you did `as String`, not `as String?`, that is where the error comes in.

To fix this, I believe it should be possible to completely remove `as String`, like this:

```
  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Article(
      source: Source.fromJson(json['source']),
      author: json['author'],
      title: json['title'],
      description: json['description'],
      url: json['url'],
      urlToImage: json['urlToImage'],
      publishedAt: json['publishedAt'],
      content: json['content'],
    );
  }
```

It is possible the above does not work, in case it doesn't the following should:

```
factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Article(
      source: Source.fromJson(json['source']),
      author: json['author'] as String?,
      title: json['title'] as String?,
      description: json['description'] as String?,
      url: json['url'] as String?,
      urlToImage: json['urlToImage'] as String?,
      publishedAt: json['publishedAt'] as String?,
      content: json['content'] as String?,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me. As you can probably tell I'm quite new to flutter so this helped loads.